How can I enable testnet4 in Bitcoin Core 28.0?
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-28.0.md#testnet4bip94-support released.
Is it possible to enable testnet4 via bitcoin.conf? How?
Right now in my config - chain=test and its works with testnet3

You can set Bitcoin Core to run in testnet4 mode by putting chain=testnet4 or testnet4=1 in the configuration, or by using equivalent command-line options (-chain=testnet4 or -testnet4).
This is contrasted with the options available for testnet3: chain=test, or chain=testnet, or testnet=1 (and equivalent command-line options -chain=test, -chain=testnet, or -testnet).

Thanks you for the answer

I also had to change section header [test] to [testnet4] in bitcoin.conf to properly enable my rpcbind config
